# Python - asyncore.dispatcher module error

Tags: python

I started learning this asyncore.dispatcher module and when I run the first example program it gives the error as per below:

**Python version 2.6**

asyncore module is installed and there is also dispatcher class inside it. What may be the problem !

**Error:**

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'
```

**Example code:**

```
import asyncore, socket

class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):

    def __init__(self, host, path):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect( (host, 80) )
        self.buffer = 'GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n' % path

    def handle_connect(self):
        pass

    def handle_close(self):
        self.close()

    def handle_read(self):
        print self.recv(8192)

    def writable(self):
        return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

    def handle_write(self):
        sent = self.send(self.buffer)
        self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]

client = HTTPClient('www.python.org', '/')
asyncore.loop()
```

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Could we get the full traceback?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncore.py", line 1, in <module>
    import asyncore, socket
  File "C:\python\asyncore.py", line 3, in <module>
    class HTTPClient(asyncore.dispatcher):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dispatcher'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that you named your file `asyncore.py`. It's shadowing the `asyncore.py` in the python standard lib so the file is importing itself instead of the real one. You want to rename your copy of the file and delete `asyncore.pyc` in the same directory if it exists. Then when you run your file, you'll be importing the `asyncore.py` from the standard library.

When Python runs the line `import asyncore`, python looks through the directories in `sys.path` for a file named `asyncore.py`. The directory of the primary file that's executing is always the first entry in it. So Python finds your file and attempts to import it. As a general rule, you should never give your files the same name as a module from the standard library if you want to use that module.